# Merge cells in table with ms word VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to merge in one cell with vba, but not working.

mycode :

```
Sub merge()
Dim x As Integer, i As Integer
x = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
      For i = 1 To x + 1
            If .Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = "" Then
            .Cell(Row:=i, Column:=2).merge _
            MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=i, Column:=3)
            .Borders.Enable = False
            End If      
      Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

In the document, I have a table (five row and three columns).

Answer (score 1):

For excel VBA code writers, it is a common conceptual problem, we used to treat a blank  cell as empty (""). but actually an apparently blank Word table cell  contains two invisible characters (at least in word 2007) i.e. `chr(13)` & `Chr(7)`. it could be tested  with simple statement like

```
MsgBox Len(.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text)
MsgBox Asc(Right(.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, 1))
MsgBox Asc(Left(.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, 1))
```

so to make your code work it may be modified to something like

```
Sub merge()
Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, S As String
x = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
      For i = 1 To x
      S = .Cell(i, 2).Range.Text
      S = Replace(S, Chr(13), "")
      S = Replace(S, Chr(7), "")
            If S = "" Then
            .Cell(Row:=i, Column:=2).merge _
            MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=i, Column:=3)
            .Borders.Enable = False
            End If
      Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

or test line may be modified to

```
If Len(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text) = 2 Then
```

also could not understand why in your code you are iterating to `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count+1` so for testing i used only `For i = 1 To x`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
If .Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = "" Then
```

to:

```
If Split(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text,vbCr)(0) = "" Then
```